# ExtJS 6.6 Community Edition available packages

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Is it possible to use charts in ExtJS 6.6 Community Edition?

I try to add them as I usually do in my app, based on ExtJS 6.2 GPL version, but it does not work. Perhaps packages need to be somehow explicitly added via npm?

In addition, in the documentation for ExtJS 6.6 CE I do not see the description of the corresponding classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately charts are not available in the CE edition. Here is an excerpt from the [Sencha Software License Agreement](https://www.sencha.com/legal/sencha-software-license-agreement/), and specifically the "*8. ADDITIONAL LICENSE TERMS APPLICABLE TO THE COMMUNITY EDITION*" section (emphasis mine):

> In the event You have obtained a Sencha Ext JS Standard Community
>   Edition license (the “Community Edition”), the following terms apply
>   in addition to the General Terms described in Section 2 above. Please
>   note that **the Community Edition does not include all the software
>   packages that Sencha Ext JS includes, and in particular does not
>   include Ext JS Classic, Ext JS Charts, and many Ext JS fonts and
>   themes**.